# how to list booking ref code and names of passengers in bookings with 3 or more passengers together with sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datagrid

here is the dataset 'ticket'

[image: ticket]

I need to retrieve a list of book_ref and names passengers in bookings with 3 or more passengers together .

I tried store the result in existed table booking_code

```
INSERT INTO booking_code
SELECT book_ref, passenger_name
FROM bookings.ticket
GROUP BY book_ref, passenger_name
/*looking for br have 2 airport
 */
HAVING COUNT( * ) >2;
```

but the result was 2 empty column of book_ref and passenger_name
I think I did not correctly use "count".

how can i fix to code so the outcome would be like this?

[image: solution]

Comment: Why is 989F9B in the result set?

Comment: maybe other 989F9B is somewhere in the result set

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want window functions:

```
SELECT t.book_ref, t.passenger_name
FROM (SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY book_ref) as book_ref_cnt
      FROM bookings.ticket t
     ) t
WHERE book_ref_cnt > 2;
```

This returns booking with more than 2 passengers in the original data.